# Custom nginx container exits immediately when part of docker-compose

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to learn how to use docker compose with a simple setup of an nginx container that reroutes requests to a ghost container. I'm using the standard ghost image but have a custom nginx image (that inherits from the standard image).

When I run the composition using "docker-compose up" it exits immediately with "docker_nginx_1 exited with code 0". However, when I build and run it manually, it runs fine and I can navigate my browser to the container and view the default nginx page. What am I misunderstanding about my compose file that causes it to behave differently than being custom built? What can I change to get it to stay running?

Disclaimer: I am also learning nginx as I go, so learning two things at once may be causing me undue problems.

EDIT: 
The original files were a bit more complex, but I've reduced the issue to simply: If I use the build command for a custom image that does nothing but inherit from the default nginx image, it exits immediately. If I use the default nginx image, it works. These are the now relevant files:

Compose file:

```
ghost:
 expose:
   - "2368"
 image: ghost

nginx:
  # image: nginx << If I use this instead of my custom build, it doesn't exit
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  links:
   - ghost
```

nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
```

ORIGINAL FILES (with the same compose file as above):

nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY conf/sites-available/ghost /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost
RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ghost

EXPOSE 80 443

# Is this even the right command I have no idea

CMD service nginx start
```

nginx/conf/nginx.conf:

```
daemon off;

user  nginx;
# Let nginx figure out the processes I guess
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

nginx/conf/sites-available/ghost

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 127.0.0.1;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Running compose-up:

```
plays-MacBook-Pro:docker play$ docker-compose up
Creating docker_ghost_1...
Creating docker_nginx_1...
Attaching to docker_ghost_1, docker_nginx_1
docker_nginx_1 exited with code 0
Gracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping docker_ghost_1... done
```

Running manually:

```
plays-MacBook-Pro:nginx play$ docker build --no-cache -t nginx_custom .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.704 kB
Step 0 : FROM nginx
 ---> 914c82c5a678
Step 1 : RUN rm /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Running in 4ce9de96bb36
 ---> 98f97a9da4fc
Removing intermediate container 4ce9de96bb36
Step 2 : ADD conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> dd3e089208a9
Removing intermediate container 36b9a47e0806
Step 3 : ADD conf/sites-available/ghost /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost
 ---> 55fae53e5810
Removing intermediate container a82741d24af4
Step 4 : RUN mkdir /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
 ---> Running in 7659ead01b7b
 ---> 406be1c42394
Removing intermediate container 7659ead01b7b
Step 5 : RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ghost
 ---> Running in e9658a08affa
 ---> 021a84216e8a
Removing intermediate container e9658a08affa
Step 6 : EXPOSE 80 443
 ---> Running in 230e4523794c
 ---> 23d85e1a04cb
Removing intermediate container 230e4523794c
Step 7 : CMD service nginx start
 ---> Running in 209e129cae21
 ---> d7004d6fa223
Removing intermediate container 209e129cae21
Successfully built d7004d6fa223
plays-MacBook-Pro:nginx play$ docker run -t nginx_custom
[It sits here on an empty line, running in the background]
```

Comment: Can you try without `COPY conf/sites-available/ghost /etc/nginx/sites-available/ghost`, jsut to see if that is an issue when used with `docker compose`?

Comment: Also, since https://github.com/dockerfile/nginx/blob/master/Dockerfile#L26 already defines a `CMD`, try without `CMD`.

Comment: @VonC Alas, it still exits immediately if I remove the COPY command, and even if I reduce it to `FROM nginx`

Comment: Came here 5 years after OP posted this question. Mine was a container running on a `Nginx:stable-alpine` image. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907197/6388351 saved me! It's sort of a hack for local development though

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just ran into this same issue, and the initial *fix* was to change the name of the service in `docker-compose.yml`.

This worked, but the **reason** it worked is because Docker-compose caches the build & ties it to the service name.  Every `docker-compose up` after the first one just uses what it built before, so any changes you make to the `Dockerfile`, or that section of the `docker-compose.yml` are basically ignored.

When you (and I) changed the service name, it triggered a new build since that service name hasn't been tagged before.

The **real** solution is to do a: [docker-compose build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) to rebuild the image (followed by a `docker-compose up`).  Their documentation doesn't really emphasize this issue.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  I had been using `docker build` but apparently when using compose you have to rebuild using `docker-compose build`

Comment: A simpler option is to use `docker-compose up --build` instead of invoking the build step manually first.

Answer (score 51):

The CMD in your `Dockerfile` should start a process which needs to run in foreground. The command `service nginx start` runs the process in deamon mode and thus your container exits cleanly because the `service` command exits.

Use the following `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` to start nginx (taken from [official image](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/4e5332fa50a1f8f73657417c6bfe249bbb3b110d/Dockerfile)) and it should work correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be fixing it. I've got `daemon off;` in the nginx.conf file, so it shouldn't be a problem with the above code. But to make sure I tested it thoroughly I made the dockerfile just be `FROM nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` and it still exits immediately. It even does with just `FROM nginx` . I'll update the question accordingly with that info.

Comment: `daemon off` isn't what is daemonizing the process. `service nginx start` tells it to run in the background, not the foreground.  This is the correct answer. If you replace `CMD service nginx start` with `CMD nginx ...` it should start in the foreground.

Comment: @dnephin While that seems true, doing so isn't the action that makes my specific configuration function properly.  Changing to `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` doesn't makes it start working. When the name in compose is changed, it functions. Whether or not it SHOULD be functioning with `service nginx start` I don't know, but it seems to. If you'd like to try it out, there's a sample repo at https://gitlab.com/merrillogic/docker-compose-nginx with two commits - nonfunctioning and working. Perhaps there's an extra factor that's making this misbehave.

Comment: I was having `CMD ["nginx"]` and container was exiting with status code of 0. Changing it to `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` perfectly fixed the issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

You can also add a

```
tty: true
```

to the service in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
webserver:
    build: .
    volumes:
        - "./src:/var/www/html"
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    depends_on:
        - aap-mysql
    tty: true
```

and it should stay running after

```
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Maybe it's not the most elegant way but it worked as other solutions did not

Comment: This is exactly the solution when using compose.

Answer (score 7):

I figured out what it was. I needed to name the nginx part of my composition something other than 'nginx' . I'm not sure if it's because there is already an nginx image or if it is something else, but changing it made it work properly.

By changing my compose file to:

```
ghost:
 expose:
   - "2368"
 image: ghost

mything:
  # image: nginx
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  links:
   - ghost
```

I was able to get it to work. An indicator was that when the name changed, I actually saw the build process output for my container. If anyone knows exactly why the naming needs to be that way, I'd love to know.

Comment: I just ran into this same issue...called my service "web".  ...and nothing worked.  ...hours of searching/tweaking for what I could have wrong in my setup eventually led me to this post.

Comment: @Merrillogic:  see my answer for `exactly why the naming needs to be that way`