# how to make docker keep running in frontend and not exit so that I could see the running log output

Tags: docker

Now I want to make a docker command run in frontend so that I could see the log output. Now I am using this command to run my docker container:

```
docker run -p 11110:11110 -p 11111:11111 -p 11112:11112 --name canal-server dolphinjiang/canal-server:v1.1.5
```

this is the `Dockerfile` of my project:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
RUN echo ZONE=\"Asia/Shanghai\" > /etc/sysconfig/clock


RUN rm -rf /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo 
COPY CentOS6-Base-163.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/
RUN yum clean all



RUN groupadd -g 2500 canal; useradd -u 2501 -g canal -d /home/canal -m canal
RUN echo canal:De@2018er | chpasswd; echo root:dockerroot | chpasswd


RUN yum -y update && yum -y install wget vi openssl.x86_64 glibc.x86_64 tar tar.x86_64 inetutils-ping net-tools telnet which file
RUN yum clean all


COPY jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz /opt
RUN tar -zvxf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt && \
        rm -rf /opt/jdk-8u291-linux-x64.tar.gz && \
                        chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk1.8.0_291 && \
                                        chown -R root:root /opt/jdk1.8.0_291
RUN echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_291' >> /etc/profile                       
RUN echo 'export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/profile
RUN source /etc/profile


RUN yum install kde-l10n-Chinese -y
RUN yum install glibc-common -y
RUN localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i zh_CN zh_CN.utf8
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk1.8.0_291
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
ENV LANG zh_CN.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL zh_CN.UTF-8


ADD canal-server /home/canal/
RUN chmod 755 /home/canal/bin


WORKDIR /home/canal/bin
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/restart.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/startup.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/stop.sh
RUN chmod 777 /home/canal/bin/config.sh
CMD  /home/canal/bin/config.sh
```

this is the `config.sh`:

```
cat > /home/canal/conf/canal.properties <<- EOF
# register ip
canal.register.ip = ${HOSTNAME}.canal-server-discovery-svc-stable.testcanal.svc.cluster.local

# canal admin config
canal.admin.manager = canal-admin-stable:8089
canal.admin.port = 11110
canal.admin.user = admin
canal.admin.passwd = 4ACFE3202A5FF5CF467898FC58AAB1D615029441
# admin auto register
canal.admin.register.auto = true
canal.admin.register.cluster = 
EOF
sh /home/canal/bin/restart.sh
```

and this is the `restart.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=$@

case $(uname) in
Linux)
  bin_abs_path=$(readlink -f $(dirname $0))
  ;;
*)
  bin_abs_path=$(cd $(dirname $0) ||exit ; pwd)
  ;;
esac

sh "$bin_abs_path"/stop.sh $args
sh "$bin_abs_path"/startup.sh $args
```

and this is the `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 

current_path=`pwd`
case "`uname`" in
    Linux)
        bin_abs_path=$(readlink -f $(dirname $0))
        ;;
    *)
        bin_abs_path=`cd $(dirname $0); pwd`
        ;;
esac
base=${bin_abs_path}/..
canal_conf=$base/conf/canal.properties
canal_local_conf=$base/conf/canal_local.properties
logback_configurationFile=$base/conf/logback.xml
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export BASE=$base

if [ -f $base/bin/canal.pid ] ; then
    echo "found canal.pid , Please run stop.sh first ,then startup.sh" 2>&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -d $base/logs/canal ] ; then 
    mkdir -p $base/logs/canal
fi

## set java path
if [ -z "$JAVA" ] ; then
  JAVA=$(which java)
fi

ALIBABA_JAVA="/usr/alibaba/java/bin/java"
TAOBAO_JAVA="/opt/taobao/java/bin/java"
if [ -z "$JAVA" ]; then
  if [ -f $ALIBABA_JAVA ] ; then
    JAVA=$ALIBABA_JAVA
  elif [ -f $TAOBAO_JAVA ] ; then
    JAVA=$TAOBAO_JAVA
  else
    echo "Cannot find a Java JDK. Please set either set JAVA or put java (>=1.5) in your PATH." 2>&2
    exit 1
  fi
fi

case "$#" 
in
0 ) 
    ;;
1 ) 
    var=$*
    if [ "$var" = "local" ]; then
        canal_conf=$canal_local_conf
    else
        if [ -f $var ] ; then 
            canal_conf=$var
        else
            echo "THE PARAMETER IS NOT CORRECT.PLEASE CHECK AGAIN."
            exit
        fi
    fi;;
2 ) 
    var=$1
    if [ "$var" = "local" ]; then
        canal_conf=$canal_local_conf
    else
        if [ -f $var ] ; then
            canal_conf=$var
        else 
            if [ "$1" = "debug" ]; then
                DEBUG_PORT=$2
                DEBUG_SUSPEND="n"
                JAVA_DEBUG_OPT="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=$DEBUG_SUSPEND"
            fi
        fi
     fi;;
* )
    echo "THE PARAMETERS MUST BE TWO OR LESS.PLEASE CHECK AGAIN."
    exit;;
esac

str=`file -L $JAVA | grep 64-bit`
if [ -n "$str" ]; then
    JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms2048m -Xmx3072m -Xmn1024m -XX:SurvivorRatio=2 -XX:PermSize=96m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss256k -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"
else
    JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m "
fi

JAVA_OPTS=" $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
CANAL_OPTS="-DappName=otter-canal -Dlogback.configurationFile=$logback_configurationFile -Dcanal.conf=$canal_conf"

if [ -e $canal_conf -a -e $logback_configurationFile ]
then 
    
    for i in $base/lib/*;
        do CLASSPATH=$i:"$CLASSPATH";
    done
    CLASSPATH="$base/conf:$CLASSPATH";
    
    echo "cd to $bin_abs_path for workaround relative path"
    cd $bin_abs_path
    
    echo LOG CONFIGURATION : $logback_configurationFile
    echo canal conf : $canal_conf 
    echo CLASSPATH :$CLASSPATH
    $JAVA $JAVA_OPTS $JAVA_DEBUG_OPT $CANAL_OPTS -classpath .:$CLASSPATH com.alibaba.otter.canal.deployer.CanalLauncher 2>&1 
    echo $! > $base/bin/canal.pid 
    
    echo "cd to $current_path for continue"
    cd $current_path
else 
    echo "canal conf("$canal_conf") OR log configration file($logback_configurationFile) is not exist,please create then first!"
fi
```

after I start the docker, it exit automaticlly, and the docker not startup, no log output. what should I do to make it run in frontend. after successs, switch to the backend. I also tried to run in deamon like this（make the container run background and not exit）:

```
docker run -it -d -p 11110:11110 -p 11111:11111 -p 11112:11112 --name canal-server canal/canal-server:v1.1.5
```

the process still exit automaticlly. and docker container did not startup.

Comment: Start with removing `-d` from your `docker run` command.

Comment: I have tried to remove `-d`, but the process still exit. @anemyte

Comment: finally I am using this script to keep the container alive and do not exit: `while true: do sleep 1 done`, I do not know if there is better way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should get the point (based on your latest comment).
Docker is based on some command, when it's done - it stops the container.

So to make it continuously running you should have command and run infinitely.

Also check this answer as well, there are more explanation
[Why docker exiting with code 0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891777/4899914)

One of the easiest solution is to tail some logs.
Like,

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55907197/4899914)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `tail -f /dev/null` to keep the container from stopping, try this

```
docker run -it -d -p 11110:11110 -p 11111:11111 -p 11112:11112 --name canal-server canal/canal-server:v1.1.5 tail -f /dev/null
```

see also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209776/docker-container-will-automatically-stop-after-docker-run-d)